# How to add a hover timeout to drop down element (and sub elements)?

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein, slidedown, jquery-hover

Here's my fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Pr3fix/LTSSx/4/

```
$(function(){
var timer;
$('.logo').hover(function(){
    $('.bubble-container').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: 600, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(600);
}, 
function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bubble-container').stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration: 600, queue: false}).slideUp(600);
    }, 3000);
});
$('.bubble-container').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
},
function(){
    $('.bubble-container').stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: 600, queue: false }).slideUp(600);
});
```

});

Right now if you hover over "logo" link, a speech bubble drop down/fade in animates into view using jQuery.

If you hover over the "logo" link, and then mouse away from it, there is a nice delay before the speech bubble hides. You can also move the mouse into the speech bubble, and the bubble will not hide while you are hovering over it. But as soon as you move the mouse out of the speech bubble, it hides straight away.

**my question is**: how can I make hovering into / out of the speech bubble act the same? I don't want it to instantly close, but rather take a few seconds so if the user accidentally bumped their mouse, it's not constantly springing open and closed. What do I need to change in my existing code to do this? Any performance or general tips?

Comment: darn. Any ideas of alternative approaches I could take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.delay(2000)` to delay the execution of an event.

**http://jsfiddle.net/LTSSx/7/**

```
$('.bubble-container').stop(true, true).delay(2000).fadeIn({ duration: 600, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(600);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer too, works good. Is there a way to make it so that the animation is a little less glitchy? Basically want it to stay open if the user is hovering anywhere on the link / box that drops down. And if the cursor is moved away, it stays for 2 seconds before hiding. If you mouse out of it then back in, it should reset the 2 sec. timeout.

Comment: @Prefix - That's basically your animation, with all the stops and use of multiple animation methods and no queue, you'll get issues.

Comment: @adeneo: ok, any alternative ways to do what I'm trying? I don't mind adding an additional plugin.

Comment: @thenewseattle: great! :)